# Convert Uint8Array to Float32Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to convert a binary array (which I receive as `Uint8Array`) to a `Float32Array`, by simply concatenating tuples of 4 bytes. I do **not** want convert each single `Uint8` to a `Float32` (which is why this is no duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669537/javascript-uint8array-to-float32array)).

It has been suggested in answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49351231/5909613) to simply do something like this (to be exact, this recommendation is actually for the conversion in the opposite direction):

```
var floatShared = new Float32Array(uint8array.buffer);
```

According to this answer, both array do now share the same buffer in the background, which would be exactly what I need. However my `floatShared` seems to not get updated properly as the length still remains 0 and I cannot inspect it in the browser.

Am I missing a step or am I going in the completely wrong direction? How can I do this conversion?

Comment: Have you looked at DataViews?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. I couldn't get it directly from UInt8Array to Float32Array. Did it in two steps:

1) Convert UInt8Array to "regular" Array of Floats

```
// utility function, creates array of numbers from `start` to `stop`, with given `step`:
const range = (start, stop, step = 1) =>
    Array(Math.ceil((stop - start) / step)).fill(start).map((x, y) => x + y * step)


// uint8 array with 2 floats inside, 1.0 and -1.0
uint8array = new Uint8Array([63, 128, 0, 0, 128 + 63, 128, 0, 0]);
numberOfFloats = uint8array.byteLength / 4;
dataView = new DataView(uint8array.buffer);
// sometimes your Uint8Array is part of larger buffer, then you will want to do this instead of line above:
// dataView = new DataView(uint8array.buffer, uint8array.byteOffset, uint8array.byteLength) 

arrayOfNumbers = range(0, numberOfFloats).map(idx => dataView.getFloat32(idx * 4, false));  
// be careful with endianness, you may want to do:
// arrayOfNumbers = range(0, numberOfFloats).map(idx => dataView.getFloat32(idx * 4, true))
```

2) Convert array of floats to Float32Array

```
float32array = new Float32Array(arrayOfNumbers)
```

This is definitely not very efficient solution, but works.

And if you just want to retrieve array of Numbers it is even not bad.